# How to convert java.hprof file to .log file format?

Tags: java

I have a java.hprof file (automatically generated after an OutOfMemoryError) which I would like to convert to the .log(text file) file. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not work like this.

You might need use this http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to read/analyse your file